# Why am I getting the error-"re.error: multiple repeat at position 2"

Tags: python, python-re

I am learning re module for the first time but  got an error .

The code-

```
import re
my_str='''pyhton
c++
java
c++
js node
ds algo
pyhton
js node
javac++
java
js node
ds algo'''
var = re.findall("c++",my_str)
```

It gives the error - `re.error: multiple repeat at position 2`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the [Python RE module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) documentation. The '+' character has a special meaning in Regex. It denotes that the previous character is repeated one or more times.

so `'c++'` as a regex actually means "the character 'c' repeated one or more times repeated one or more times"

To actually identify the character '+', you need to escape it with a `'\'`. So your regex becomes `'c\+\+'`.

I always recommend  using an online regex editor to try-out your regexes in an interactive way. [regexr](https://regexr.com) and [regex101](https://regex101.com/) are good examples of such editors.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer with the green checkmark near (under?) the voting buttons! Good luck with the rest of your learning trajectory. Regexes can be quite hard to get a grasp off, but very powerfull once you understand them!